# Passing text box value from view, to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClockIn", "Login", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Member.PIN)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Member.PIN)<br />

    <button type="submit">ClockIn</button>
}
```

and here is the controller ClockIn controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClockIn(String Pin)//member clocking in
    {
        var mem = _context.Members.Where(c => c.PIN == Pin).FirstOrDefault();
        var hours = new MemberClubHours();
        hours.ClockIn = DateTime.Now;
        mem.Hours.Add(hours);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

I have a members class with a PIN value that they use to clock-in and track their hours, but for some reason, I keep getting a null value in the controller ? I know I have the PIN in the member table and I'm entering the correct PIN so I'm just a little confused why the PIN in the controller is null?

Comment: change String to string . String is class and string is an alias. String is generally use to access the static members of String. and by using "string" you dont need to add additional namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form seems posting the Member object not just the `Pin`. But you are trying to capture "Pin" as a `string`.

There are many ways to do it, but you can try capturing the whole member object and get the PIN out of it. Something like below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClockIn(Member member)//member clocking in
    {

       var mem = _context.Members.Where(c => c.PIN == member.PIN).FirstOrDefault();
       var hours = new MemberClubHours();
       hours.ClockIn = DateTime.Now;
       mem.Hours.Add(hours);
       _context.SaveChanges();

       return View();
   }
```

PS: I haven't tried this on code editor, so there might be a type or something.

Comment: Thank you, that helped!